# c++ overload method argument with original method's argument derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I have the following objects

```
#include <stdio.h>

class foo_t{ };
class bar_t: public foo_t{ };
class zoo_t: public bar_t{ };

class base_t{
public:
   void dostuff(foo_t * foo){ printf("Defaulting to base\n"); };
};
class derived_t: public base_t{
public:
   void dostuff(bar_t * bar){ printf("Overloading with derived\n"); };
};

int main(){
    derived_t derived;
    zoo_t zoo;
    derived.dostuff(&zoo);
}
```

I see it is doing what I mean, but I would like you to confirm that this is not just a coincidence.

What I mean is that I want C++ to resolve the method that "gets closer" to the specialized class zoo_t. In this case the first ancestor found is bar_t which determines that the derived_t class method is invoked. Is this the way C++ resolves overloaded methods when arguments are both specialized and base classes?

Comment: Your `zoo_t zoo` `is-a` `bar_t`, since it inherits publicly. As such, the derived function is called, since you're calling it via `derived.dostuff`. The same thing would happen with `derived.dostuff(&bar)` if you had a `bar` object, but I'm pretty sure your compiler would complain if you tried `derived.dostuff(&foo)` since `foo_t` objects are not `bar_t` objects.

Comment: By which I mean - it's not the parameter you're passing that's choosing your function - it's the way that you're calling it.

Comment: Well if you're not using virtual methods, the base class methods of the same name will be hidden, so the only choice left to the compiler will be the various prototypes of the said method in your derived class.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I see your functions are not `virtual`. I will assume that's intended and leave `virtual` out of discussion.

You normally don't overload a base class's member functions in a derived class; you *hide* them instead. Which means that `base_t::dostuff` is not accessible through an object-accessing expression of type `derived_t`. In other words, this won't compile:

```
int main()
{
  derived_t derived;
  foo_t foo;
  derived.dostuff(&foo);
}
```

However, this will:

```
int main()
{
  derived_t derived;
  foo_t foo;
  base_t& base = derived;
  base.dostuff(&foo);
  derived.base_t::dostuff(&foo);
}
```

This has other implications as well. For example the code below will print `Defaulting to base`:

```
int main()
{
  derived_t derived;
  zoo_t zoo;
  base_t& base = derived;
  base.dostuff(&zoo);
}
```

To summarize - which function gets called is based on the type of the expression choosing the object (the expression to the left of `.` or `->`), and that type *only.* That will always work that way, so if that's the behaviour you're after, you're fine.

If you want to really *overload* the inherited function instead of *hiding* it, you can use a `using` declaration:

```
class derived_t: public base_t{
public:
   void dostuff(bar_t * bar){ printf("Overloading with derived\n"); };
   using bas_t::dostuff;
};
```

Then, the following code will work:

```
int main()
{
  derived_t derived;
  foo_t foo;
  bar_t bar;
  zoo_t zoo;
  derived.dostuff(&foo); // calls base
  derived.dostuff(&bar); // calls derived
  derived.dostuff(&zoo); // calss derived
}
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/M3A7Id)